# What is the PyTorch equivalent to Numpy's linalg.solve?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have looked it up and there are some posts, for example [this one](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solving-linear-equations-is-very-slow/17774), that suggest to use `torch.gesv` but I can't seem to find it in the PyTorch documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pytorch provides the function `torch.solve`, which behaves like `numpy.linalg.solve`. It will output the solution of the the linear system and the LU factorization that has been used to compute it. 
More information and example codes [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.solve).

Answer (score 4):

Pytorch now has a [linalg](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/linalg.html) part very similar to NumPy. So you can do [torch.linalg.solve](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/linalg.html#torch.linalg.solve) and expect the same behavior as NumPy.