# How PyTorch's linalg.solve is implemented?

Tags: matrix, pytorch, linear-algebra, solver

There are many methods for solving a linear system `AX = B` where `A.shape == (n, n)`. My computer runs the following code in 5-10 seconds in CPU:

```
A, B = torch.randn(10000,10000), torch.randn(10000)
torch.linalg.solve(A, B)
```

Gaussian elemination has `O(n^3)` time complexity, so, as a first guess, one expects about `10000^3 = 10^12` operations to solve this system. But this cannot be the case, as the clock speed of my processor is 2.4*10^9.

My question is how PyTorch implements the solver? Does it use an iterative algorithm, or an optimized Gaussian elemination? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736548/6087087) claims that it is implemented with LU-factorization, but isn't it also a O(n^3) algorithm?